# Soft subtitles on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, mp4

I know this question (or similar ones) has been asked all over the Web, but I still can't find a straight answer:

1. Is it possible to mux soft subtitles into an mp4 video file (quickly, without re-encoding the video stream) that iPhone will actually display on the screen? I have tried ffmpeg, MP4Box, Subler, Submerge and mp4v2 and none of them were successful in producing mp4 file that would display subtitles on iPhone (though some of them had subtitles when playing the video in VLC or iTunes).
2. If iPhone does not support soft subtitles in mp4 files, then is there any command line utility (like the ones mentioned in question 1) that will render hard subtitles onto the video stream? (I guess then this process will take hours since the video will have to be re-encoded)
3. Finally, if there is no command line utility that can do hard subtitles, what options are there for GUI-based utilities? Is Handbrake the best option?

If possible, please supply a command line example.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, there is closed captions, but it is not same as subtitles
2. mplayer
3. Ask on superuser.com :)